# Dynamically setting size of frame of a UITableView which is placed in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

I am using swift and have a story board containing a UIViewController which includes a UIScrollView with UITableView. 
[image: storyboard hierarchy]

What am I trying to do is to load an excel file in a table so I need to scroll horizontally. I can set the content size of scroll view with:

scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 3500, height: scrollView.contentSize.height)

I do also need to set the size of frame of UITableView. When I set it from storyboard with the field shown it works, but when I set it programmatically from viewDidLoad method it does not work. The width value is shown as changed to 3500 but when I checked in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I see the value set in story board.

[image: Need to change this from code]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you putting a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView`? `UITableView` has its own internal `UIScrollView`.

Comment: I could not scroll horizontally before putting UITableView inside UIScrollView. I am new to IOS development and just thought that I can scroll horizontally only by putting in because I could not scroll without it. If I don't create a separate scrollview, how can I set content size of the internal scroll view?

Comment: Well, technically, `UITableView` *is* a `UIScrollView`; it is a subclass. You can access `contentSize` directly.

Comment: Yes, just realized, and since I have another scrollview it has no effect right now. Will try by deleting UIScrollView and let you know.

Comment: I deleted UIScrollView and set the contentSize of tableView but unfortunately can not scroll horizontally. (Came back where I started to think that I have to use a UIScrollView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample project I just created to see if I could create what you are asking for.

https://github.com/joalbright/Excel

Comment: Thank you very much. Just checked the project. You have 3000/200 = 15 columns. So saw that you set the frame size of table view to 3000 from story board. My exact problem is I will have to set number of columns thus frame size of table view dynamically via code.

Comment: Updated project to make tableView width dynamic. Have a constraint on the tableView and programmatically change its width.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I need:) Thank you very much. But could you please tell me what am I doing wrong before? I set tableview.frame to be as wide as I need.

Comment: And what do you think about "tableview already contains a scrollview and Apple documentation discourages from embedding UITableView inside UIScrollView"

Comment: It is normally bad to have multiple scrollviews within each other... more for if they both are scrolling the same direction. If you are correctly managing it, having a vertical scrollview inside a horizontal scrollview is fine.

Comment: As for what you were doing wrong... nothing. Just Apple has some behind the scenes things that refresh the tableView width... the constraint overrides their manipulations.

Comment: Fascinating solution! I noticed that you  have @IBOutlet 'weak var tableVIewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!' which is shown as being connected to the storyboard control. What did you have to do to get that connected to the storyboard?

Comment: @JoAlbright is there a way you to show another example, but instead of horizontal, vertical?. I mean, depending on how many rows you have, the tableView height will dynamically update its frame height

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html) discourages you from embedding `UITableView` inside `UIScrollView`.

> You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

Anyway are your `UITableView` and `UIScrollView` scrolling horizontally?

Comment: Hmm, seems that I am struggling with that unexpected behavior.

Comment: Yes I can scroll horizıontally but the problem is tableView ends even there are more content on right. So I thought that I have to change the size of the frame of tableView. When I set it to a big value from story board as stated above, everything is fine.