# Scrolling horizontally in UITableView to see a long cell in Xcode 6 & Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a tableviewcontroller and added a table view to it. What I need is simply to view a long cell (or row) by swiping right. How can I do this?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Will definitely check it, thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Just add a simple UIScrollView inside of your tableCell as below. This will allow you to have horizontal scrolling within the cell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    /// Horizontal Scroll

    var scrollview = UIScrollView(frame: cell.bounds)
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(cell.bounds.width * 5, cell.bounds.height) // will be 5 times as wide as the cell
    scrollview.pagingEnabled = true

    cell.contentView.addSubview(scrollview)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: But I do not want to scroll cells individually,  scroll right like an excel sheet, all cells together...

Comment: You could wrap the tableView in a scrollView... make the tableView as wide as you need to cover all of the columns you want... then the tableView will scroll all columns up and down... and the scrollView will scroll all of the rows left and right.

Comment: In fact tried this and failed, please check my other question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889027/dynamically-setting-size-of-frame-of-a-uitableview-which-is-placed-in-uiscrollvi/26889508#26889508

Comment: Submitted an answer to your other question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

var tableviwe:UITableView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableviwe = UITableView(frame: self.view!.bounds)
    self.tableviwe!.delegate = self
    self.tableviwe!.dataSource = self;
    self.tableviwe?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    let angle:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI_2);//angle角度 double angle;
    self.tableviwe?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)
    self.view?.addSubview(self.tableviwe!)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "Alert"
    alert.message = NSString(format: "%@ %d", "My hit ", indexPath.row)
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
    alert.show()
}
//UITableViewDataSource
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1000
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    return 200.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "channel")
    cell.textLabel?.text = NSString(format: "%@ %d", "hello my friend", indexPath.row)
    let angle:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI_2);//angle角度 double angle;
    cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle)
    return cell
}

}
```